# How do I place multiple divs that contain text and a floated image so they flow down the page one at a time and don't overlap?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a custom helper which returns a html string. Which outputs the follow html code:

```
<div>
    <div class='floatRight'>
         <img height='300' src='{0}' />
    </div>
    <div class='clearFloat'>
        <h4>{1}</h4>
        <p>{2}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this is placed inside a foreach loop I want it to show the heading and paragraph text with the image inline to the right of it. If the height of the image is bigger than the heading and text then I want the next heading and text to appear below the the line of the previous image. However the result I get is a Left-Down diagonal positioning of images. I'm sure this is an easy fix but nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure if this a float problem or a div problem since the images flow into other divs. Basically I want the very outer div to expand with the greater of: the height of the image, or text so that the next div will be placed under that and not just under the text part.

For a more visual example I am looking for something will replicate this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Text Text Text Text Text </p>
        </td>
        <td><img width="300" height=300" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was trying to avoid to avoid tables but maybe floating divs are just as bad.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you’re trying to achieve? Floats are generally not the best solution for layout.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like your problem is that you were attempting to use floats.

Solution below. Let me know if I’m misunderstanding what you’re trying to do.

```css
/* Demo Styles
-------------------------------- */
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
li:nth-child(1) img { background:dodgerblue }
li:nth-child(2) img { background:gold }
li:nth-child(3) img { background:red }



/* Reset Default Browser Styles
-------------------------------- */
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

li {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Layout
-------------------------------- */
/* All direct children of the list element */
li > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div>
    <h1>Your title</h1>
    <p>The description of descriptions of descriptions</p>
  </div>
  <img>
</li>

<li>
  <div>
    <h1>Your title</h1>
    <p>The description of descriptions of descriptions</p>
  </div>
  <img>
</li>

<li>
  <div>
    <h1>Your title</h1>
    <p>The description of descriptions of descriptions</p>
  </div>
  <img>
</li>
```

Editable demo: [http://jsbin.com/puveba/2](http://jsbin.com/puveba/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: This is very close to what I want thank you. Is it possible to make it so that when the space is smaller the text will wrap and keep the image to the side instead of placing the image underneath?

Comment: It is possible but there aren’t any "good" solutions short of using flexbox. Modified demo here: http://jsbin.com/puveba/5/edit?html,css,output. Note in IE9 and below you’ll need an additional set of layout rules since flexbox is not supported.